# How to delete table data in HTML?

Tags: html

I want to delete the datas I put in the cells of a table. I just want to delete the data nothing else, how can I do that in HTML? This is my table and I want to delete the datas in the table:

```
<table style="width:100%" style="height:10%" id="table1">
<tr id="vmi">
<td class="cella" id="tr0td1"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr0td2"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr0td3"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr0td4"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr0td5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cella" id="tr1td1"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr1td2"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr1td3"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr1td4"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr1td5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cella" id="tr2td1"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr2td2"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr2td3"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr2td4"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr2td5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cella" id="tr3td1"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr3td2"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr3td3"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr3td4"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr3td5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cella" id="tr4td1"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr4td2"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr4td3"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr4td4"></td>
<td class="cella" id="tr4td5"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't without a server side language.

Comment: What do refer to as "data"? The table seems to be empty. You *can* delete any kind of data from a table, but you will have to use JavaScript. HTML will not do it.

Comment: I  write something in the cell, e.g. "Something" and I want to add a button that deletes this text from the cell.

Answer (score 3):

You can use some JavaScript code like

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("#table1 td")].forEach(td=>td.innerHTML="")
```

This would delete all contents from all cells in the table.

If you place a button like this on your page

```
<button id="clrall">clear all cells</button>
```

Then you can assign the action to this button with

```
document.querySelector("#clrall").addEventListener("click",ev=>
[...document.querySelectorAll("#table1 td")].forEach(td=>td.innerHTML=""))
```

If, on the other hand, you want to delete the content from individual cells, like the one you click on, then you could do it by binding an appropriate click event handler to the cells of the table.

```
document.querySelector("#table1")
.addEventListener("click",function(ev){
  if (ev.target.tagName=="TD") ev.target.innerHTML=""; 
})
```

Comment: So I just have to add: 
function something(){
document.querySelectorAll("#table1 td").forEach(td=>td.innerHTML="");
}
And that's all?

Comment: Yes, you can run that code by putting it in the function as you have written or you can directly bind it to some button click event.